# Upgrade my Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database on my apps, but I have 2 problems:

- The Database name don't correspond to which i writted:

An error:

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table demandes has no column named dateEnvoie, db=/data/data/(package)/databases/google_analytics_v4.db
```

My code :

```
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Solutis";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_DEMANDES = "demandes";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_XML = "xml";
private static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE = "statutEnvoie";
private static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE = "dateEnvoie";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Error say that my db name is = google_analytics_v4.db but in my code DATABASE_NAME = "Solutis".

- My second problem is the Database Upgrade, I did some changes (i added a column)

I have to call it:

```
// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DEMANDES);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

But how to do ? I'm working in a Fragment, what I pass in parameters ?

---

### CODE

```
    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        // All Static variables
        // Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Solutis";

        // Contacts table name
        private static final String TABLE_DEMANDES = "demandes";

        // Contacts Table Columns names
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_XML = "xml";
        private static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE = "statutEnvoie";
        private static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE = "dateEnvoie";

        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        // Creating Tables
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DEMANDES + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_XML + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_STATUTENVOIE + " INTEGER" + KEY_DATEENVOIE + " DATETIME" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE);
        }

        // Upgrading database
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DEMANDES);

            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db);
        }
(functons...)
    }
```

---

```
public class DemandeGratuite extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //placer ici le code pour connaitre la densite et la resolution de lecran
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demande_gratuite, container, false);
        valider.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                            db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

                            xml = "...";

                            Demande demande = db.addDemande(new Demande(xml, 0, ""));

                            demandeId = demande.getID();

                            db.updateIdContactClient(demandeId);

                    }
                }
        );


        return view;
    }
```

Comment: you'd have to show your connection code. that's where the problem is occuring.

Comment: @MarcB My connction code ? It's a db created in the phone memory, you want the code of the database creation ?

Comment: pretty much. wherever you try and tell android to open your `Solutis` db, because that's undoubtedly not working correctly, otherwise you wouldn't be connected to the analytics db.

Comment: Since you modified your database schema, uninstall and reinstall your app. Or increase the value of `DATABASE_VERSION`.

Comment: @DerGol...lum Sure but what I put for context ?

Comment: @DerGol...lum And why the database name is not the good ?

Comment: **1** Use `getApplicationContext()` (or `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`, if in a Fragment) **2** use the proper file name.

Comment: @DerGol...lum Im in a fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I've noticed is that the string `CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE` you created is improperly formatted as an SQL statement. You missed a comma before `KEY_DATEENVOIE` so it is not being recognized as a table in the database. Change the string to:

```
String CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DEMANDES + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_XML + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_STATUTENVOIE + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATEENVOIE + " DATETIME" + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the database is not being updated with your changes. In order to get the `onUpgrade` method to be called, and make your changes you need to update your database version number. Change `DATABASE_VERSION` to `2`.

Comment: Okay I did now when i call the function what I put for context? (im in a fragment)

Comment: You don't actually every call `onUpgrade` manually. If you need to query the database, then you need to create a database helper class to do that. Information on working with the DB can be found at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: In my tutorial they say that onUpgrade() is called when database is upgraded like modifying the table structure

Comment: I think it doesn't update because I have a problem with my db name